# Changing file permission in Ubuntu Live mode

Tags: permissions, live-cd

How do I change the file permission of a file to 700 ?

I am using Ubuntu Live CD.
I tried 
sudo chmod 777 abc

It does not change the permission and still shows:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu   18 2012-01-14 03:02 abc
```

Using Latest Ubuntu 11+

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell without knowing where the file is, but, making an educated guess, I'd say the file might be on a read only file system. If that's the case, `chmod` won't work.

It would also not work of the file is on a non-linux file system like FAT or NTFS. Linux permissions only work on Linux file systems.

Comment: The file is on d: drive. Not on CD of course !! :) I can create files on that drive by can not change file permissions.

Comment: @shantanuo The output of `mount` says if the drive is mounted *rw* or *ro* (read-write/read-only).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to change file permissions on files in LiveCD? You can't because CD is mounted as read-only.